# Is it possible to manually flag files in the Solution Explorer in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

I have a large number of business rule modules (C# code) in a solution folder and I want to keep track of which ones have been implemented.

Every file has stub code but I want to be able to manually apply some sort of flag (like a bookmark) to the file in the Solution Explorer once I've coded it so I can see at a glance which ones are done.

Is there a way of doing this in Visual Studio 2013? Failing that is there some sort of Visual Studio extension that would do the same?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried Favorite Documents extension?

https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/d4ab8421-147f-4416-8038-d5f7fdcf6a56

It is free extension which lets you create links to frequently used code files and then quickly open them as a group or individually from the Favorites menu in Visual Studio 2010, Visual Studio 2012, and Visual Studio 2013.

Comment: [Are answers that just contain links elsewhere really “good answers”?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers)

Comment: That is great but the file still looks the same in the solution explorer.

Comment: @SonerGönül "It doesn't matter whether a cat is white or black, as long as it catches mice"